# Loop for print screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, loops, screenshot

Need some help. I got this python code to load url and take a screen print.

I need to achieve this:

1. instead of array, read url from text file
2. take screen print of each url that is loaded and save it. with the code the screen print is over written

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = ["http://google.com", "http://cisco.com"]
for element in url:
    driver.get(element)
    driver.get_screenshot_as_file("screenshot.png")
sleep(2)
driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

Comment: To read something from a text file, use `file = open("filename.txt")` and then `var = file.read()`. The variable `var` will then have the contents of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the URLs in a text file and then read line by line. Then take screenshot using file name with the host name of the URL.

I have modified your code and could store the screenshot of each url in separate file. I have used Python 3.6.9.

Directory structure:

```
.
├── links.txt
├── requirements.txt
└── screenshots_of_links.py
```

`links.txt`:

```
http://google.com
http://cisco.com
```

`requirements.txt`:

```
selenium==3.141.0
urllib3==1.25.10
```

`screenshots_of_links.py`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from time import sleep


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

with open("links.txt") as url_file:
    for line in url_file.readlines():
        url = line.strip()
        if url != "":        
            driver.get(url)
            host = urlparse(url).hostname
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("{}.png".format(host))            
            sleep(2)

driver.quit()
print("end...")
```

**Output**:

[image: cisco.com]

[image: google.com]

**Modification details**:

- Read the URLs from `links.txt` text file.
- Trim each line of the file.
- Parsed each URL and used the hostname as filename of screenshot. `urlparse(url).hostname` returns the hostname of a valid URL.

**Reference**:

- [URL parsing Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#url-parsing)